# how to do Live chart or Live datagrid in silverlight 4 with RIA service and Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

can anyone tell me how i can do a Live chart/datagrid with using RIA service and Entity Framework 4 in silverlight 4?
So whenever the data has been updated in the database, then the corresponding row or chart will update automatically

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to refresh collection that binds with your datagrid or chart in duration of few time span.